# Twitter Bootstrap tabs - use as normal anchor tag behaviour. Uncaught Error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

This is baking my noodle beyond belief. So I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/aVBUy/1/) to demonstrate my problem. But the fiddle actually works.

Ok. I want to use bootstap tabs - only for their look, so not using their bootstrap behaviour.

I simply want the anchor href to work as normal default behaviour. So when a tab is clicked, the browser redirect to href. Just like a normal anchor tag would work.

So I setup my tab a navigation mark up...

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="subTabs">

    <li class="active"><a href="http://mywebsite.com">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/individual">Individual</a></li>   
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/studio/">Studio</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/location/">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/engineers-images/">Engineers</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/tech-sketch-images/">Technical Sketch</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/videos/">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/documents/">Documents</a></li>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#subTabs a').click(function (e) {
        return true 
    })
</script>
```

which outputs the tabs as normal.

So when I click the tabs on a iphone/ipad, it works fine.

But when I click it on a desktop browser I just get this js error, and nothing happens.

[image]

Which is just bonkers.

Because with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/aVBUy/1/) I created, which is exactly the same, it works fine!!!

Can anyone help me please understand what is wrong.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/aVBUy/1/

---

For temporary measures I am having to do this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#subTabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    })
</script>
```

But just before page redirects you can see the same error occur.

But you surely dont need js to make a link clickable right?

How can I remove the bootstrap tab default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This click event shouldn't be nessecary. The html code looks fine. 
At least if you have posted all js code. The fiddle you have linked to is without the js part, so thats why it's working.

But if you need this js for some reason, which I don't think is the case, you are missing some semicolons. And I would put the eventhandler in the `ready` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subTabs a').click(function(e) {
        return true; 
    });
});
```

The reason why it looks like its working on touch devices could be, that the click isn't even triggered there.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. Well if I dont include jQuery code, the behaviour is the same. The tabs work on iphone/ipad but get the nasty syntax error every time on desktop browsers.

Comment: The only thing you need for a navigation with standard link behaviour is the html with the css classes, like [documented](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs).
Is there a reason that you have `bootstrap.js` included in your code?

Comment: I feel like such a idiot. Just found the bug. I had a scrollto event using the nav class which had preventDefault in it. Thanks for you time tho, sorry for wasting it :/